# Ejecutar scripts creados en el html desde html

Tags: html

Estoy iniciándome con el tema de los `scripts` en `html` y no consigo que esto funcione:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Tests</title>
        <script>
            readvalue();
            sum();
            result();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <script>
            function readvalue(){
                var string = window.prompt("Enter the information", "");
            }

            function sum(string){
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Me salta el error en el navegador de:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: readvalue is not defined

Tambien necesito trabajar con ese `string` en dos funciones mas. 
¿Alguna ayuda de como manejar esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que declarar primeros las funciones y luego llamarlas así:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tests</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
    
    
    function readvalue(){
      var string = window.prompt("Enter the information", "");
      return string;
    }

    function sum(string){
      alert(string);
    }
    
    var valor = readvalue();
    
    if(valor != null){
      sum(valor);
    }
    //result();

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

La función `result()` no existe.

Comment: Si se que el result no existe. La tengo que hacer aun. Debo de poner sum(string) para llamarla? O no hace falta?

Comment: El string es el que recojo en redvalue().

Comment: Listo edite mi respuesta para que veas como se llama sum(), esta es una función que espera un parámetro y dentro de esa función hice un alert para que te saliera en la pantalla un recuadro con el string que le pasas en este caso "Hola"

Comment: @David_helo acabo de editar mi respuesta revisala ahi se juntan las dos funciones

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Obvie el return en mi función.